# Kohana ORM table join

Tags: join, orm, kohana-3

I have 2 tables

1. user (id, name, position_id)
2. position (id, name)

how can i join the to models, so i can do something like this.

```
ORM::factory('user')->position()->name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/ORM#property:_belongs_to

```
class Model_User extends ORM {

   protected $_belongs_to = array(
       'position' => array('model' => 'Position')
   );

}
```

Now you can:

```
ORM::factory('User')->with('postion')->find()->position->name;
```

Or indeed, with an already loaded user (e.g. `$user = ORM::factory('User', 1);`

```
$user->position->name;
```